# Cardview Swipe Vertically

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-fragments

I am trying to make a cardview be able to swipe down vertically. I know it has to do something with a listener and a drag listener but nothing seems to work. What I have is something along of what I believe should be the steps but I am lost on how to make the card view draggable/swipeable down. Any assistance is appreciated.

activity.main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardviewbackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-175dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="18dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ticket_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:text="Test Ticket"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity<T> : AppCompatActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
    val listener = View.OnDragListener { view, event ->
        when(event.action) {
            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED -> {
                event.clipDescription.hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)

            }
            else -> false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add onDragListener to your parent view like

```
containerView.setOnDragListener(View.OnDragListener{v,e-> 
        e.x
        e.y
        return@OnDragListener true
    })
```

Hide your view and create a duplicate dialog view as your card view get x and y from listener and calculate it based on your view and touch position when action touch start

```
private fun getMovinCard(x: Int, y: Int/*first add position*/):Dialog {
    val dialog = Dialog(activity)
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    val window = dialog.window
    window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.card_view) //your card view gois here
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
    val wmlp = dialog.window!!.attributes
    if (items.size > 5) wmlp.height = activity.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.drop_down_height).toInt()
    wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP or Gravity.START //set as yuor need
    wmlp.x = x
    wmlp.y = y 
    dialog.show()
    return dialog
}
```

then on e.action event move your view

```
private fun moveCard(x: Int, y: Int, dialog: Dialog) {
    val wmlp = dialog.window!!.attributes
    wmlp.x = x
    wmlp.y = y 
}
```

you can handle view as your action events

and if your purpose to drag and drop then use android standard Drag and drop framwork
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop

Comment: Thank you for the help-I understand what you're writing but I am having a hard time implementing it and making it work. Do I call getMovingCard and moveCard somewhere? what do I put in for activity in Dialog(activity)? I would just like to be able too swipe the cardview down  175 dp

Comment: Dialog(activity) put activity context. getModingCard will return a window dialog. That later can be put any where on screen based on supplied x,y values. I have not done exactly what you want. but i showed view at clicked location.There i was passing clicked x,y position. So this should work in your case also

Comment: okay thanks im trying this but iam not getting the correct outcome